# Is there any delay in laser scanner output?

Tags: ros, laser-scan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am working on erratic robot and I am running it in gazebo. It has a hokuyo laser scanner on it. I have a question that is there any delay in laser scanner output.

What I am doing here is that I have written a simple code that moves erratic robot and avoids it from obstacles and reaches at goal position. Here I performed a simple experiment 2 or 3 times, I placed an obstacle of same size at same location every time. Now when I move my robot to goal position it avoids and reach at goal position successfully but the problem is that every time robot has a different trajectory.

How can I have same trajectory every time?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38266/is-there-any-delay-in-laser-scanner-output?/) by [abdullah](https://answers.ros.org/users/1083/abdullah/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2012-07-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On a real robot you probably can't have exactly the same trajectory every time.

There is always delay in any sensor. Plus, there are random odometry errors and actuator errors. There will also be random timing variation in the arrival of various messages from independent sources.

Depending on how you implement your navigation algorithm, you may be able to minimize many of those random factors with a feedback control loop.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [abdullah](https://answers.ros.org/users/1083/abdullah/) on 2012-07-09**:
thanks a lot. Its very helping.